# Proper use of OR in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I am having trouble using the "OR" operators in CF. I have tried writing many different or statements and none seem to work they are stopping at the first 'eq' to:

```
<cfif form.chosen eq 'Vickih' || 'AlyssaH'>
<cfif form.chosen eq 'Vickih' or 'AlyssaH'>
```

Am I just mistyping or misusing the "OR" statement? I need to make a list of like 8 names. I am trying to prevent the "else if" repeating the same code over and over.

Any help is greatly appreciated. The docs I am looking up say this should work. But the code is not running with the second name only the first name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
<cfif form.chosen eq 'Vickih' OR form.chosen eq 'AlyssaH'>
```

you could use the listFind or listFindNoCase function and do something like this:

```
<cfif listFindNoCase('Vickih,AlyssaH',form.chosen)>
```

[Adobe documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-l/listfindnocase.html)

Comment: +1 for ListFind/NoCase when using multiple values. Once you reach 3 or more comparisons, it makes things a lot more readable.